# Easiest way to move Outlook 2007 emails to GMail?

Tags: outlook, gmail

I've decided to move completely away from my old POP3 email accounts and into GMail.

I have a lot of archived mail in a Outlook 2007 .pst file.

I know I could just forward them from Outlook, but then I would receive them as only one email with a lot of attachments in GMail?

How can I move these into my GMail?

Answer (score 4):

The most foolproof way I think is add your Gmail account to Outlook and move the messages within Outlook. Don't have any experience, but Google gives a lot of useful results.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully moved several thousand massages from Outlook to GMail by connecting to my GMail account via IMAP and just moving them into the right folder.

I happened to export all my messages into Thunderbird first because of an article that suggested doing that then using the [Google GMail Loader](http://www.marklyon.org/gmail). But when I realized that the article predated GMail's implementation of IMAP I just configured an IMAP account in Thunderbird and did some drag-n-dropping. I'm pretty sure Outlook supports IMAP accounts so you could skip that intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

Erick -> I tried the GMail Loader but without any luck.

PEZ -> If I forward mail they will get attached at as mail to the forwarded mail and that way I will be unable to see the subject of the mails.

I think I will try adding my GMail account to Outlook and try moving everything inside Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

miies's answer looks promising. If it fails maybe you can make a filter rule in outlook that forwards the messages and apply it to your mail folder.